# Using browserify with a minified JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, browserify, commonjs

1. Can a minified JavaScript library be "required" and bundled using Browserify? In other words, does Browserify require the JavaScript file to be in source format?
2. If a JavaScript file is not a CommonJS module (does not export anything), can it be bundled using Browserify? In other words, What does `require('xyz.js')` do if xyz.js is not a CommonJS module.

Comment: 1. Yes, browserify just needs any require('') and module.exports to be intact.  2. `require('xyz.js')` runs xyz.js the first time it's required then doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks @generalhenry. For question 2 then, if I have a JavaScript file that is not a CommonJS module, how do I browserify it? Or should I not even try to do that?

Comment: You simply use a relative path from your entrypoint  eg `require('./vendor/xyz.js')`.  Browserify is best with commonjs, but it works fine with any js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In case it's properly exporting its properties (e.g. using exports or module.exports) and loading modules using `require()` then yes.
2. Of course it can be bundled, but you can't access its properties/data from the result of the `require()` call. However if it's using for example the global object for its exports, you can access it after you require the file.

xyz.js:

```
window.myExport = "hello";
```

main.js:

```
var xyz = require("xyz");
xyz.myExport; // undefined
window.myExport; // "hello"
```

Comment: Thanks @Radek. To follow up on your answer #2, is it a good practice to require such files anyway? Or should they be included in the html file using <script> tags?

Comment: It's hard to say. I like to require all my files even when they are not CommonJS modules, because I don't really like having more script tags than just one. Which is also kind of a good practice. So it's on you, just choose the option which is better and more logical for you. ;-)