# Use Browserify with JavaScript libraries such as Backbone or Underscore?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, browserify

I know I can install underscore using `npm` but that's not what I can do in my work environment. I need to be able to download the Underscore.js library and then make it "browserify-compatible".

So let's assume Underscore.js looks something like this:

```
(function() {
    var root = this;

    // Rest of the code

}.call(this));
```

I downloaded that file on my hard drive and saved it as under.js.

My file that requires underscore looks like this:

```
var underscore = require("./under");
console.log(underscore);
```

And then I run `browserify` from the cli.

I have an HTML page called `test.html` and basically all it does is load the generated `bundle.js`.

However, the `console.log(underscore)` line fails - says that `underscore` is `undefined`.

**What have I tried?**

Obviously I added `module.exports` to the first line - right before the function definition in under.js, and that's how I got the error mentioned above. I also tried the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874139/using-browserify-with-a-minified-javascript-library) , still got the same error.

So, how would I use Browserify to load libraries such as Underscore.js or Backbone without using `npm`-installed modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because browserify does not add variables to the global scope.  The version you download is identical to the version that you install via NPM.

You need to explicitly attach it to the window to export it to the top level scope.

If you create a file called "expose_underscore.js" and put this in it:

```
var _ = require('./under');
window._ = _;
```

Will do it, followed by: `browserify expose_underscore.js > bundle.js` and then add `bundle.js` as a `<script>` tag you will be able to do the following in your console:

[image: it does work]

HOWEVER, you shouldn't do this if you're using browserify.  The point behind it (and Node's version of commonJS) is that you explicitly require it everywhere you need it.  So every file you have that needs underscore should import it to a local variable.

Don't worry -- you will still only have one copy loaded.

Comment: Thanks, but this still does not work. I've changed my `console.log` to `console.log(window._.contains([1, 2], 1))` and I tried `console.log(_.contains([1, 2,], 1))` - still gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined `

Comment: How are you calling browserify?

Comment: Here is a gist of the files I created to verify this works: https://gist.github.com/toddself/c5cc2bfbb4e34dfd49c0

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort! I realized what the problem was - I always added `module.exports` to my underscore.js file. It is not needed, and I am an idiot. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, underscore exports itself using a universal module definition -- it can attach to the `window`, return itself for AMD or attach itself to `module.exports` as necessary for the environment.

Answer (score 0):

I typically add my vendor libs like Underscore as script tags.  Underscore will attach itself to the global scope, so then you don't need to require it anywhere to use it.

If you do want to use it in a Browserified fashion, verify that you have the correct path in your require statement (browserify requires are relative paths) and move the module.exports statement to the end of the file.

Comment: I wish I had the liberty of adding libraries as script tags, but one of the main reasons I want to use Browserify is because I can't do that. I do have the correct path in the `require` statement, but I'm not sure what do you mean by moving the `module.exports` statement to the end of the file? How, when the entire Underscore is wrapped in one function?